# Javascript: how can I export a variable found through the Chrome Memory tab?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am trying to get the points from from a graph, I managed to find the variable in the memory but, for some reason, I cant access it from Chrome console.

The page is https://www.etoro.com/people/hyjbrighter/chart and I think they are using Angular.

D.t.ChartEngine.Chart is not defined...

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Have you saved it and looked at the data in the file?

Comment: @epascarello: yes, but looks to me a bit messy.. I mean that it seems unsorted

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's seems it's not possible to save only a specific variable. I saved the whole file and worked on it.